# How to create custom close case button when checked multiple chekboxes and click to close case button status should be closed?

Tags: apex

I want to create close case button on list view on case object.If you checked multiple checkboxes and click to close case button  selected checkboxes list status should  be closed. I am new to salesforce anyone plz help how to do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mass actions for list views on LEX](https://youtu.be/Q7Yoqhnisgw?t=95). You can use a Mass Quick Action.

> A mass quick action is a quick action that gets added to an object’s
>   search layout. After a mass quick action is set up, you can select up
>   to 100 records in a list view and perform mass updates. You can use a
>   mass quick action with cases, leads, accounts, campaigns, contacts,
>   opportunities, work orders, and custom objects that support quick
>   actions and have a search layout in Lightning Experience. You can’t
>   perform mass quick actions on a Recently Viewed list.

[Documentation link.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mass_quick_actions_create.htm&type=5)